# Working with calculating extra large numbers in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, math

I'm making a calculator in Flutter and I'm using the pow() function to do the power counts. I noticed that dart cannot store very large numbers as the result of 100^13 does not result in -2537764290115403776.
How can I solve this problem?

```
double m = pow(msg, e!).toDouble();
```

Comment: This is what the [`BigInt` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/BigInt-class.html) is for.