# Why pow() function in python and pow() function in dart produces different result for same input?

Tags: python, dart

I want to evaluate `pow(17,18)` in Dart language, but it produces `6665467901046659617`. In Python language the same expression `pow(17,18)` produces `14063084452067724991009`.

I want to achieve the same result in Dart also.

Comment: Integers don't overflow in python, but looks like that isn't the case in dart. You might have better luck asking how to calculate big integers in dart. Your question is unrelated to python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949952/working-with-calculating-extra-large-numbers-in-dart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Dart runs into an overflow at some point and does not (like Python) support arbitrarily large integers.

You are likely using Dart 2, which has a limit of 64 bits for integers. The maxint for that size is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Dart 1 did have a similar integer math implementation to Python, allowing integers of arbitrary size (limited by available memory only).

So, it makes sense that you're seeing a value like 6,665,467,901,046,659,617, which is just the result of `pow(17,18)` modulo the maximum integer value for Dart 2 + 1.

However, Dart 2 still has [BigInt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/BigInt-class.html), exactly for this purpose. As user @mmcdon20 indicated in the comments, you're looking for:

```
BigInt.from(17).pow(18)
```

Comment: better: "modulo the maximum integer value + 1" or "modulo 2 ** 64"

Comment: pedantic, but no less true ;-) - thanks. (edited)

Comment: This is correct, you can use `BigInt.from(17).pow(18)` in dart to get the same answer.